# C#, Assign an Action to a Delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, type-conversion, action

I understand that an `Action` is a `Delegate`, but I'm receiving the following compile time error trying to assign an `Action` to a `Delegate`.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Action' to 'ADelegate'

```
public delegate void ADelegate();
Action act = () => Console.WriteLine ("test");
ADelegate del = act;
```

How can I assign `act` to `del`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C# doesn't support casting or converting between delegate types.

Try creating a new `ADelegate` like this:

```
Action act = () => Console.WriteLine ("test");
ADelegate del = new ADelegate(act);
```

Or alternatively:

```
Action act = () => Console.WriteLine ("test");
ADelegate del = act.Invoke;
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you not just do this?

```
public delegate void ADelegate();
ADelegate del = () => Console.WriteLine("test");
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You might get more upvotes that way!